# Why would an attachment file_size value be null?

Tags: siebel

I am wondering in which scenarios attachments would have a null value in the file_size column.

In particular I am looking at activity attachments.  When is the file_size value populated?  Does Siebel read the file properties at the point of upload?

I am looking at data quality and at this point I am unsure as to why a lot of attachments have no file_size value stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Siebel populates all the attachment information (name, extension, size, etc.) when the file is created.

Notice that there are two types of attachment: `FILE` and `URL`. You can distinguish them with the `FILE_SRC_TYPE` column. The field is also exposed in most attachment applets. For the URL attachments, the file size is always stored with a `NULL` value.

If you find any file-type attachment with null or 0 size, that's incorrect data. I can only imagine 3 scenarios where this could happen:

- An error in the file creation.
- A custom script updating the field value. I don't know if that's even possible, it's a system column.
- Somebody updating the value directly in the database.

There is a fourth scenario: uploading an empty file, which actually has 0 size. However, in this case, the file size shown in Siebel wouldn't be 0. I've just done the test, and Siebel shows a file size of 71 bytes. According to the [Bookshelf](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B31104_02/books/SystAdm/SystAdm_SrvrInfAdm7.html), *the file size displayed in the GUI represents the size of the compressed .saf file, not the actual file size*. Which also explains why URL attachments don't have a size at all.

Comment: Perfect, thanks.  Looks like I've got a few corrupt attachments.